# I can not start debug for my webapp in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Can anyone help me with the problem. When I'd started the debug for web app in netbeans I got error:

FAIL - Deployed application at context path /Events but context failed to start.

How can I fix that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone. The problem was in web.xml